# Regex to match any image URLs besides ones that are commented out

Tags: python, regex

[This](https://regex101.com/r/HSRBzs/1/) is the Regex I have for Python:

```
^(?<!(<!--.))(http(s?):)?([\/|\.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
```

The current expression matches this:

```
/images/lol/hallo.png
```

but I need it to match this image url:

```
/images/lol/hallo.png
```

and this image url without the surrounding tags:

```
<img src="/images/lol/hallo.png" />
```

but not these that are commented out:

```
<!-- /images/lol/hallo.png -->
<!-- <img src="/images/lol/hallo.png" /> -->
```

Comment: Use `<!--[\s\S]*?-->|((?:https?:)?[\w\s/.-]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)\b)` and grab Group 1 value. You may simply use it with `re.findall` and filter out empty values after.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how do I grab Group 1 value in Python?

Comment: Just try it with `re.findall`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: See [here](https://regex101.com/r/PVleDL/1), you need those green ones. With `re.findall`, you will get only them. And empty items, since it will match those you do not want, but they won't be put into the resulting list.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, if there will be 2 URLs  line by line - it will join them. I see that you've added space instead of \s, but that can be and issue.

Comment: @wowkin2 It is not quite possible in real life. But it is also possible to use `(?:https?:)?(?:(?!https?://)[\w\s/.-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PVleDL/2).

Comment: @Kris.Kodira Show your code.  I suspect you could not make it work because you wrote it like `"my regex"` while you should have written `r"<!--[\s\S]*?-->|((?:https?:)?[\w\s/.-]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)\b)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<!--[\s\S]*?-->|(?P<url>(http(s?):)?\/?\/?[^,;" \n\t>]+?\.(jpg|gif|png))
```

Test string:

```
<img src="/images/lol/hallo.png" />
    /images/lol/hallo.png
    /images/lol/hallo.png
    //example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    http://example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    https://example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    <!-- /images/lol/commented.png -->
    <!-- <img src="/images/lol/commented2.png" /> -->
    images/ui/paper-icon-1.png


/images/lol/hallo.png and more here /images/lol/hallo.png
```

Python code:

```
import re

x = '''
    <img src="/images/lol/hallo.png" />
    /images/lol/hallo.png
    /images/lol/hallo.png
    //example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    http://example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    https://example.com/images/lol/hallo.png
    <!-- /images/lol/commented.png -->
    <!-- <img src="/images/lol/commented2.png" /> -->
    images/ui/paper-icon-1.png


/images/lol/hallo.png and more here /images/lol/hallo.png
'''
regexp = r'<!--[\s\S]*?-->|(?P<url>(http(s?):)?\/?\/?[^,;" \n\t>]+?\.(jpg|gif|png))'
result = [item[0] for item in re.findall(regexp, x) if item[0]]
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YmXo2Q/4

Comment: The regex based on `.+` would not work here - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/39VjxH/4).

Comment: Nice catch! But for that case, the @Kris.Kodira will need either add all extensions, or use `[\w\d]+` instead

Comment: @wowkin2 I modified it slightly to [this](https://regex101.com/r/YmXo2Q/2) and now it seems to be working like it should. If you edit your answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @wowkin2 I corrected it once more and now it seems to be perfect [here](https://regex101.com/r/YmXo2Q/3) it is. It wasn't matching relative image paths.